# I need to calculate difference between start and end date excluding weekends and federal holidays with the response formatted in H:MM

Tags: excel, date

I want to format the output so that it displays in Hours:Min as opposed to an integer.

`=text(NETWORKDAYS(H10,J10,Holidays!E10:E39)-1),"H:MM")`

Comment: ... and what is not working with your current formula?

Comment: the outcome is 0:00; but should be 23:27 based on J10 - H10, H)

Comment: Some sample data or a screenshot of your setup would be helpful here

Comment: let say.. the answer is an integer 7. just do `=(7*24)&":00"` will do right?

Comment: according to [THIS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7), NETWORKDAYS `Returns the number of whole working days between start_date and end_date`  Basically it will always be blocks of 24 hours.  You can format the value `[HH]:mm` but it will always be a multiple of 24.